# spring-boot foreign key not found

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a sprint-boot 1.1.4.RELEASE app that uses liquibase and postgresql.

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long menuId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "menu", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "subscriptionPackageId", nullable = false)
    private SubscriptionPackage subscriptionPackage;

    private String displayText;
    private int displayOrder;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class MenuItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long menuItemId;

    private String displayText;
    private String path;
    private String toolTip;
    private int displayOrder;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "menuId", nullable = false)
    private Menu menu;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "callType", nullable = false)
    private HttpType callType;
```

I have the following in my db.changelog-master.xml:

```
    <databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd"
        objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS">

    <changeSet id="1" author="me" >
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <tableExists tableName="SubscriptionPackage"/>
                <tableExists tableName="Menu"/>
                <tableExists tableName="MenuItem"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>

        <createSequence sequenceName="hibernate_sequence"/>

        <createTable tableName="SubscriptionPackage">
            <column name="subscriptionPackageId" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="servicePackage" type="varchar(300)"/>
            <column name="description" type="varchar(500)"/>
        </createTable>


        <createTable tableName="Menu">
            <column name="menuId" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="subscriptionPackageId" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="displayText" type="varchar(300)"/>
            <column name="displayOrder" type="int"/>
        </createTable>

        <createTable tableName="MenuItem">
            <column name="menuItemId" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="menuId" type="bigint">
                <!--<constraints foreignKeyName="fk_menu_item" references="Menu(menuId)"/>-->
            </column>
            <column name="displayText" type="varchar(100)"/>
            <column name="path" type="varchar(100)"/>
            <column name="toolTip" type="varchar(500)"/>
            <column name="displayOrder" type="int"/>
            <column name="callType" type="varchar(50)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

which gets executed on start up and postgresql shows me the following sql for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Menu"
(
  "menuId" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "subscriptionPackageId" bigint,
  "displayText" character varying(300),
  "displayOrder" integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_menu PRIMARY KEY ("menuId")
)

CREATE TABLE "MenuItem"
(
  "menuItemId" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "menuId" bigint,
  "displayText" character varying(100),
  path character varying(100),
  "toolTip" character varying(500),
  "displayOrder" integer,
  "callType" character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT pk_menuitem PRIMARY KEY ("menuItemId"),
  CONSTRAINT fk_menu_item FOREIGN KEY ("menuId")
      REFERENCES "Menu" ("menuId") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I have a MenuRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface MenuRepository extends CrudRepository<Menu, Long> {
    List<Menu> findAll();
    List<Menu> findBySubscriptionPackage( SubscriptionPackage subscriptionPackage);
}
```

On startup, the following line causing an exception:

```
List<Menu> menus = menuRepository.findAll()
```

which is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "menu" does not exist
  Position: 166
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
```

The sql that is being submitted is:

```
select menu0_.menu_id as menu_id1_0_, menu0_.display_order as display_2_0_, menu0_.display_text as display_3_0_, menu0_.subscription_package_id as subscrip4_0_ from menu menu0_
```

I think my mappings are fine, the Menu contains many MenuItems in a bi-directional relationship.  I have some other mappings that are failing with the same type of issue, and those have underscores rather than camel case in the relation error name; which makes me wonder if this is a side effect of me using **spring.jpa.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy**

Based upon "a_horse_with_no_name" excellent suggestions, I manually created the Menu table via SQL without quotes and I got another error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column menu0_.menu_id does not exist
```

This is also a case issue, so I must be configuring Liquibase incorrectly to tell Postgresql to ignore case and camelcase.

I have tried the following in my changelog:

```
objectQuotingStrategy="LEGACY"
objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS"
objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ONLY_RESERVED_WORDS"
```

and all three create my tables and columns with quotes.

Comment: You created your tables with quoted identifiers which means they are case-sensitive now. `"Menu"` is a different table name than `menu`. I would recommend to re-create all tables without any quotes. That will give you far less trouble in the long run.

Comment: I don't see where I created the tables with quotes.  I defined them in XML for liquibase.  Do you mean this is a case sensitivity issue and I should use the @Table(name="menu") or whatever so the case is correct?  I am not sure I follow what you mean.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE "MenuItem"` - maybe it's the way you defined them in Liquibase.

Comment: I don't see how to tell Liquibase to create the db tables without that.  If I understand you, my table and Entity are named "Menu" while the relationship is "menu"? I have another error where the table is SubscriptionPackage and missing relation is "subscription_package"  is that also a case sensitive issue?

Comment: OK, so I manually created the Menu table via SQL without the quotes and that got me past that error, and on to other errors: ERROR: column menu0_.menu_id does not exist  So this does look like a quoting/case/camelCase issue.  As I am using Liquibase to create and manage my database, what am I doing wrong?  I will update my question to show the entire change file.

Comment: I don't find any reference to `objectQuotingStrategy` in the Liquibase manual. What happens if you write all names in lowercase? (or uppercase - just not with mixed case).

Comment: I changed the table names to uppercase in the xml and then referenced them as @Table(name="MENU") in my entity.  That gets me back to the columns not being found.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got all the issues worked out and am posting in case someone else is having the same issues.  It would seem that Spring-Boot, or something, is expecting the column names to have underscores instead of camelCase.  I changed my liquibase changeset to be:

```
 <createTable tableName="MENU">
            <column name="menu_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="subscription_package_id" type="bigint"/>
            <column name="display_text" type="varchar(300)"/>
            <column name="display_order" type="int"/>
        </createTable>
```

I then also have to declare the table name on each entity as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MENU")
public class Menu {
...
}
```

where there is an "_" between the entity cases.  I don't know if there is a way to override this, or even if I should, like I do with the EJBNamingStrategy.  I could not find it documented anywhere, but I happened to notice it on a integration test in the spring-boot flyway project.

This feels wrong, I don't recall having to declare the table name on the entities before, but I am new to Postgresql so I can't say if its because it is case sensitive or where the issue is.  I would love to hear back on if this is correct, of if I am making a mistake somewhere.